# Why the directory created after WORKDIR disappear

Tags: docker

Currently, I have the following docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ADD . /var/www/html/xxx
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/debug1
WORKDIR /var/www/html/xxx
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/xxx/debug2
```

After `docker-compose up -d`

I went inside the container by using the following command

```
docker exec -it xxx_xxx_1 bash
```

To my suprise

- `/tmp/debug1` is created
- `/var/www/html/xxx/debug2` is ***not*** created

However, if I went inside the container using

```
docker run -it xxx bash
```

What I realize is that

- `/tmp/debug1` is created
- `/var/www/html/xxx/debug2` is created

May I know why there is such behavior, after line WORKDIR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like volumes being in play. Can you update your question with your compose file?

I assume that you have defined a volume in the compose file which mounts something to `/var/www/html`

If this is true, then this would explain what you see. When you run the container without compose, you see `/var/www/html/xxx/debug2` because `/var/www/html` contains the content originally created at docker build time. If you run it with compose, docker mounts a host directory or a docker volume onto `/var/www/html`, in which case everything that was originally there get "invisible". If your volume/host-dir is empty, then `/var/www/html` is also empty.